# Golang server crashing on Heroku

Tags: web-services, heroku, go

I'm running my Golang service on Heroku. Very weirdly I have small hickups in that service that seem to be quite random. The service is simply written in Golang and does not interact with any database, storage solution or caching services.

I contacted the Heroku support already and they hinted me at this happening mainly during dyno-restart. They told me that albeit preboot is enabled when a dyno is recycled that the new dyno is coming up and takes traffic immediately and then the old one is shut off. Hence I would think that maybe the interruptions come from the Golang HTTP server not starting up fast enough? Here's how I run it:

```
s := &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":"+exposePort,
    Handler:        h,
    ReadTimeout:    time.Duration(timeout) * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   time.Duration(timeout) * time.Second,
}

err = s.ListenAndServe()
errs <- fmt.Errorf("Server error", err.Error())
if client != nil {
    client.CaptureMessage(err.Error())
}

go func() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT)
    errs <- fmt.Errorf("%s", <-c)
}()
```

Is this a known issue or has someone experienced similar so far? Would really appreciate some help with that!

Comment: What error exactly do you encounter? I'm not sure to fully grasp the issue here

Comment: It seems like the webserver is not able to quickly enough process requests. E.g. a couple of hundreds are dopped in the first seconds/minute

Comment: getting that h10 error myself

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but is there anything after the code snippet you provided? If not, the goroutine at the end is probably not ever executing. A go process exits when its main goroutine exits, and if you start a goroutine immediately before the end of your `main`, the process will kill it before it can do anything.